# panel with a toggle timer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, panel

I am trying to create a panel that will turn on and off when I press a toggle button. So far I have this:

```py
import panel as pn
pn.extension() # for Jupyter Notebook

def some_widget(gather: bool):
    if not gather: 
        yield f'{toggle.value}, {gather}'
        return

    i = 0
    for i in range(30):
        if not toggle.value: break
        try:
            yield f'{i}, {toggle.value}, {gather}'
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
        except Exception as e:
            yield f'{e}'
    yield f'done, {toggle.value}'


toggle = pn.widgets.Toggle(name='toggle')
dashboard = pn.Column(
    toggle,
    pn.bind(some_widget, toggle)
)
dashboard
```

The problem is that when the function is in the for loop the value of the `toggle.value` does not change. Hence, while within the function I cannot use the toggle button to stop the loop. Any help in allowing the toggle to stop the function will be greatly appreciated.